# Laravel fetch only one value from databse without stdClass Object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, query-builder

Hello people here is my code below...

```
        $uid = DB::table('users')
                     ->where('email', '=', Input::get('email'))
                     ->select('email')
                     ->get();

                    print_R ($uid);
```

this will output `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [email] => myemail@someemail.om ) )` I want only `[email] => myemail@someemail.om` so that i can save in session, Without using `foreach loop` can we get an outfput `[0] => stdClass Object`  ????

Comment: @JayBhatt Bhatt i would have accepted your answer, if u had put it in answer.. :)

Comment: This is more of a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Laravel 4, there is a great helper that does just what you need. Here is the update code for your example :

```
$uid = DB::table('users')
        ->where('email', '=', Input::get('email'))
        ->pluck('email');
```

As for laravel3 the docs state that upper example changes to :

```
$uid = DB::table('users')
        ->where('email', '=', Input::get('email'))
        ->only('email');
```